# MongoDB aggregate pipeline with $out operation issue

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is there a way to avoiding removing matched documents when using the "$out" operation on the same collection as the aggregated collection?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            "foo": "$bar",
            "bar": "$foo"
        }
    }
},
{
    $out: "collection"
}])
```

that query will add the result to "collection" but will remove the matched documents
when `$out: "test"` will add the result to the "test" collection while keeping the matched documents in the "collection"

is there a way **not** removing those matched documents when the output collection is the same?

** $merge cannot be used because it cannot write to the same collection in version 4.2

Comment: Use `data: {$push: "$$ROOT"}` in the group stage.

Comment: didnt work.
still, the matched documents vanished after the operation

Comment: In Mongo 4.4 you can use stage `{ $unionWith: "collection" }`

Comment: but then ill need to query on two collections instead of one.
i prefer doing two queries find and update then find with union